# XAML Binding Failure on binding an Array of data to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, datagrid

I am working on a C# UWP project and am attempting to bind a data source in my application ("dr_equipment") to a DataGrid. This was working before, but after making some changes to my JSON structure (the Equipment data type of dr_equipment), I am now getting binding errors on this data.
Visually, the DataGrid is displayed with the correct columns, but all rows are empty.

I am not sure exactly what I did that broke this, but my error is indicating that the 'attributes' property does not exist on my EquipmentData object. I reviewed the class and  there is an 'attributes' property, which is public, but it is not recognizing that for some reason.

Additional context:

- My XAML has not changed since it was last working, just the data structures.
- I do not have a seperate ViewModel. I store the data in an Equipment object (with Equipment.data[i].attributes storing the different attributes I bind) in the Page code-behind.
- I can confirm that dr_equipment.data[] is filled (array size about 1800), and each .data.attributes is appropriately filled with data. I would assume this is not an issue with how the JSON is serialized/deserialized, but some issue with the class itself.

Here are the binding errors:

```html
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'attributes' property not found on 'myProject.Classes.User_Data.Objects.EquipmentData'. 
BindingExpression: Path='data.attributes.status' DataItem='myProject.Classes.User_Data.Objects.EquipmentData'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CheckBox' (Name='null'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Boolean')
```

Here is my XAML:

```html
<controls:DataGrid
    x:Name="dataGrid"
    x:FieldModifier="Public"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=dr_equipment.data}">
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn
            Width="40"
            Binding="{Binding attributes.status}"
            CanUserReorder="False"
            CanUserResize="False"
            CanUserSort="False"
            Header=""
            IsReadOnly="False" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Here are the classes for and related to "Equipment" (type for dr_equipment):

```html
// The purpose of extending DrupalObject is that DrupalObject contains generic data
// about the Drupal object that is relatively universal to these types of objects. 
// Equipment adds additional attributes (which both serialize into 
// Equipment.data.attributes)

public class Equipment : DrupalObject
{
    public new EquipmentData[] data
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public Equipment()
    {

    }
}

public class EquipmentData : DrupalData
{
    public EquipmentAttributes attributes
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class EquipmentAttributes : DrupalAttributes
{
    public int drupal_internal__nid
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string title
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public bool status
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

And here are the classes for DrupalObject, which Equipment extends (Equipment : DrupalObject):

```html
public class DrupalObject
{
    public DrupalData[] data { get; set; }

    public DrupalObject()
    {

    }
}

public class DrupalData
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DrupalAttributes attributes { get; set; }
}

public class DrupalAttributes
{
    public int drupal_internal__tid
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public bool status
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string name
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public object description
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public DateTime created
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public DateTime changed 
    { 
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to change it from a way works to a way not working? Better to share the data structures used to work. Make a compare of them.

Comment: I changed the data structure because I hadn't developed functions for nodes yet, just taxonomy. So the structure for nodes (Equipment) needed to be updated, which no longer works with the DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the naming of the members in your class `EquipmentData`, `EquipmentAttributes attributes` have the same name as `DrupalAttributes attributes` in inherited `DrupalData`.

The following is my test code, I hope it will help you understand it.

```
   <Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid
    x:Name="dataGrid"
    x:FieldModifier="Public"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay, Path=dr_equipment.data}">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="id" 
            Width="SizeToCells"
            Binding="{Binding id}" 
            FontSize="20" />

                <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn
            Width="100"
            Binding="{Binding eq_attributes.status}"        
            Header="status"/>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </controls:DataGrid>

    </Grid>
```

---

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Equipment dr_equipment =new Equipment();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        EquipmentAttributes attributes_0 = new EquipmentAttributes { 
                status=true
        };

        EquipmentAttributes attributes_1 = new EquipmentAttributes
        {
            status = false
        };

        EquipmentData[] equipment = new EquipmentData[] {
            new EquipmentData{ id = "001",type = "safe" , eq_attributes= attributes_0},
            new EquipmentData{ id = "002",type = "happy", eq_attributes= attributes_1},
            new EquipmentData{ id = "003",type = "safe" , eq_attributes= attributes_0},
            new EquipmentData{ id = "004",type = "happy", eq_attributes= attributes_1}
        };

        dr_equipment.data = equipment;

    }
}

public class Equipment : DrupalObject
{
    public new EquipmentData[] data
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public Equipment()
    {

    }
}

public class EquipmentData : DrupalData
{
    public EquipmentAttributes eq_attributes
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class EquipmentAttributes : DrupalAttributes
{
    public int drupal_internal__nid
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string title
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public bool status
    {
        get; set;
    }
}


public class DrupalObject
{
    public DrupalData[] data { get; set; }

    public DrupalObject()
    {

    }
}

public class DrupalData
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

    public DrupalAttributes attributes { get; set; }
 
}

public class DrupalAttributes
{
    public int drupal_internal__tid
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public bool status
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string name
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public object description
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public DateTime created
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public DateTime changed
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Junjie, I will accept your answer since it identified the root problem here, but your code did not work for me. The main issues were that data_0 and data_1 did not conform to my JSON, so none of the data deserialized into those structures. Also, some of the data I wanted to bind to was in data_0 and some in data_1. I was not able to do this in the data grid, since my x:Bind statement needed to be either data_0 or data_1, not both.

Comment: My workaround that got this working was to remove the linkage between Equipment and DrupalObject, and instead implement the missing fields directly into Equipment. After some minor tweaks to my code-behind for deserializing the data, I was able to get this working with no changes to my XAML.